# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ContactComponent: (?)

Tags: angular, typescript

After npm install, I run angular code it gives me following error Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ContactComponent: (?). anybody tell me why??

here is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onGotoClick($event: any) {
    console.log($event.target.value);
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    // this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you have not included the 'RouterModule' in the module where this component is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your contact component constructor has dependencies that are not resolved.